# SearchBar using TextField in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, tableview, searchbar

I am trying to create a search bar display using textfield.

As soon as I type "@" in the textField, the table view should appear and if I remove or there is no "@" in the textField the table view should stay hidden. The search results are displayed in table view. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var disp:[String] = []

    var arrValues:[String] = ["Delhi", "Noida", "Gurugram", "Bangluru", "Nasik", "Mumbai", "Kolkata"]

    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    @IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {

        var txt = text1.text

        let fValue = txt?.index(after: (txt?.characters.index(of: "@"))!)

        let prnt = txt?[fValue!]

        let chnge = String(prnt!)

        display.text = chnge


   }

   override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.isHidden = true

     if text1.isEnabled {

        if ((otherString?.range(of: "@")) != nil) {

            tableView.isHidden = false

        }
        }
        //else{ tableView.isHidden = false}


        let anotherArr = Array(fetch!.characters)

        for chartr in anotherArr {

            if chartr == "@"{

                tableView.isHidden = false
            }
        }



 self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrValues.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.arrValues[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }


}
```